# Thymeleaf won't fetch pages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-boot

this is my Spring Boot with Thymeleaf setup.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

ThymeleafConfig

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class WebController {

    @RequestMapping("")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Index.html is located in src/main/resources/templates.

But when localhost:8080 is called only "index" string is rendered. Index.html is not fetched. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using a `@RestController`.

All handler methods of a `@RestController` bean act as if annotated with `@ResponseBody`, ie. the object they return is written to the response directly based on some `HttpMessageConverter`.

Change `@RestController` to `@Controller` if you don't want that behavior.